# Raspberry pi can't connect to internet after setting up static IP

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am on Jessie, connected via ethernet. I attempted to set up a static IP address, but after that can't connect to the internet. Details as follows:

eth0 inet addr: 10.6.1.230

cat /etc/resolv.conf: 10.6.42.1

I have added the following to the top of my /etc/dhcpcd.conf:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=10.6.1.230/24
static routers=10.6.1.1
static domain_name_servers=10.6.42.1
```

My /etc/network/interfaces file has been left as default.

I rebooted, and now when I attempt to ping anything (8.8.8.8) I get:

```
From 10.6.1.230 icmp_seq=X Destination Host Unreachable.
```

ip route show:

```
default via 10.6.1.1 dev eth0 metric 202
10.6.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernal scope link src 10.6.1.230 metric 202
```

Before this I was able to use my pi online and remote desktop into it, but now I am not after trying to set up a static IP from my pi. What could be my problem, how can I troubleshoot this? Thank you.

Comment: Show your routing table: `ip route show`. Any reason why you don't set the static address in /etc/network/interfaces directly, choosing to misuse dhcpcd for that?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the way you did it using `dhcpcd.conf` is the correct one for stretch. For jessie one should use the `/etc/network/interfaces` file for that purpose.

Comment: Everywhere I have looked shows dhcpcd.conf being the correct way to set a static IP for Jessie (https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address-update). I have now gotten my IP to change when using ifconfig, but a cannot establish an internet connection.